# Install requirejs optimizer (nodejs) on AWS python elasticbeanstalk environment

Tags: node.js, requirejs, rpm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yum

I have a python-based AWS elasticbeanstalk application which I am trying to use to deploy a python application which needs to run the requirejs optimizer.
To optimize my requirejs code, I need either NodeJS (preferred) or another way to run the requirejs optimizer.

How can I install nodejs on an elasticbeanstalk python environment?

I have tried using yum, and rpm but can't find nodejs packages.
Ideally, it will be installed by changing configs in the elasticbeanstalk's .ebextensions/.config file.

Thanks

Comment: Mike, could you possibly create an answer entry for your question, even though you solved it yourself? Thus the question will go away from the unanswered queue? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found the answer:**

instead of using the packages config to install node

```
packages:
  yum:
    nodejs: []
```

I used a custom command to install nodejs using yum with a custom config enabling the epel repo

```
container_commands:
  01_install_node:
    command: "yum install -y --enablerepo=epel nodejs"
```

I can confirm that node is now installed on the environment and can run the requirejs optimizer.